# 404 error in spring mvc with default template

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new to SpringSource,
and I created a Spring MVC Project from template,
and I did nothing but Run on Server `home.jsp` file
But I got `404 error`

I didn't know what to do
because there is no error in my console.
What can I do?
please help me.

Here it is what I get in the console
Thanks in advance.

*(I can't attach a image because I don't have enough reputation points.)*

```
6월 17, 2013 1:47:04 오전 com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tc Runtime property decoder using memory-based key
6월 17, 2013 1:47:04 오전 com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tcServer Runtime property decoder has been initialized in 200 ms
6월 17, 2013 1:47:04 오전 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
6월 17, 2013 1:47:04 오전 com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener init
INFO: Started up JMX registry on 127.0.0.1:6969 in 86 ms
6월 17, 2013 1:47:04 오전 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 638 ms
6월 17, 2013 1:47:04 오전 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
6월 17, 2013 1:47:04 오전 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.8.2.RELEASE/7.0.35.B.RELEASE
6월 17, 2013 1:47:04 오전 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost\test.xml
6월 17, 2013 1:47:04 오전 org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:test' did not find a matching property.
6월 17, 2013 1:47:05 오전 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
6월 17, 2013 1:47:05 오전 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jun 17 01:47:05 KST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2db55393: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 201 ms
6월 17, 2013 1:47:05 오전 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Jun 17 01:47:05 KST 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@73ca0d49: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,homeController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2db55393
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.test.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 540 ms
6월 17, 2013 1:47:06 오전 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\manager
6월 17, 2013 1:47:06 오전 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\ROOT
6월 17, 2013 1:47:06 오전 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
6월 17, 2013 1:47:06 오전 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1684 ms
```

Here is my home.jsp file.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world!  
</h1>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
</body>
</html>
```

and my web.xml file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: This is the current log of the application and there is no problem here (otherwise you would see an `ERROR` entry).

Comment: can you show your config?

Comment: 404 error is not from Java not Spring MVC nor any of these technologies, it means that the page you're trying to access hasn't been found. This could be caused probably for a wrong mapping of your files.

Comment: Show your jsp,  controller and Web. Xml

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yeah.. I couldn't see an ERROR anywhere..

Comment: @NandkumarTekale my config?? you mean  web.xml file?

Comment: @VaibhavRaj Roger. I added my jsp and xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to access `http://localhost:8080/your-context-root/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp`?

If so, try accessing this:
`http://localhost:8080/your-context-root/`

You will see "Hello world!".

Comment: oh.. It works!!! I just acccessed http://localhost:8080/my-root/
and I could see the page. 
Very very thank you.
I'm just wondering.. so.. what was the problem..?
Is there any configuration to modify?

Comment: Your configuration is correct. The problem is that you were just accessing the wrong URL. I would recommend reading reference documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) to learn how Spring MVC maps incoming requests to the controller.

Comment: Yeah. I got it. I need to learn how Spring framework works.
It's very helpful. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when creating the default Spring MVC project in Eclipse. Generally when you see a 404 it’s a problem with your root context path to your application as you gathered.

In eclipse you can find this set in a file under PROJECT_NAME/.settings/**org.eclipse.wst.common.component**.

```
<property name="context-root" value="my_app"/>
```

Hence `http://localhost:8080/my_app` would work.

Also check /Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server/**server.xml** for

```
<Context docBase="project_name " path="/my_app" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:eatin"/>
```